# model.fetch success callback does not fire on firefox, but works on chrome

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a success callback for a model fetch, and everything works fine on chrome, but on firefox the event does not fire. The request gets completed though, according to the console.

Code Sample:

Parent Class Function:

```
DownloadUserPromotions: (callback) ->
    self = @
    @model = new app.models.client({ id: JSON.parse($.cookie('jsondata')).id })

    lm = ->
      console.log "4"
      window.USER = self.model
      if typeof callback == 'function' then callback.call()   

    @model.fetch
      success: lm
      data: 
        relationships: 'client_promotions'
    console.log "3"
```

View Function:

```
render: ->      
    self = @
    self.ReadUserInfo()
    console.log "1"
    renderTemplate = ->
      console.log "5"
      #Below Issue is wierd.......#TODO
      @USER = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(@USER))
      $(self.el).html clientsPromotionsTemplate
        promos: USER.client_promotions
      $('.spinner#load').hide()
      self.FadeIn()

    $('.spinner#load').show()
    console.log "2"
    @DownloadUserPromotions renderTemplate  
    @
```

**Side Note:** The marked TODO is a different issue. Bonus thank yous for helping me figure out why JSON works only in that convoluted manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my success callback was part of a JSON object, firefox couldn't find whatever default it was looking for and therefore didn't fire anything. Specifying dataType:'json' when fetching solves this problem, because firefox knows where to look for the success call back.

Chrome is apparently reads my mind...

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to get your head the difference between => and -> for defining functions in coffeescript.

=>   binds *this* inside the function to what *this* was when the function was *defined*.

->  binds *this* inside the function to what *this* was when the function is *called*

```
self = this
```

is code smell sign in coffeescript that you don't understand how to use the above correctly as you are trying to capture *this* in order to solve the problem that => solves.

You render function re-written could be

```
render: ->
    @ReadUserInfo()
    console.log "1"
    renderTemplate = =>
      console.log "5"
      #Below Issue is wierd.......#TODO
      @USER = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(@USER))
      $(@.el).html clientsPromotionsTemplate
        promos: USER.client_promotions
      $('.spinner#load').hide()
      @.FadeIn()

    $('.spinner#load').show()
    console.log "2"
    @DownloadUserPromotions renderTemplate
    @
```

And probably will fix some of your wierd issues. Previously I'm pretty sure
that the line you had

```
    @USER = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(@USER))
```

would never have worked as you expected as @USER would be expanded to this.USER and
whatever *this* might be when the callback is invoked can be pretty random depending
on your framework and browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the => vs ->. Just changed a lot of my code to reflect my learning. The binding wasn't the issue with USER. It still throws up an error if I don't do that roundabout way to get the object.