# model.fetch always going to error callback

Tags: backbone.js

```
var mdl = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:{
                url:'/displayPostVariables.php',
                age:0
            },
            initialize:function(opt){                   
                this.url = function (){
                    return opt.url
                }
            }
        })
        mdli = new mdl({
            'name' :'rajkamal'
        })

        jQuery.ajaxSetup({
            'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html")
            }
        })
        mdli.fetch({
            success : successcallback,
            error:errorcallback

        });
```

Ajax call is going but, always ends up with the error callback.
Looks like this post [model.fetch success callback does not fire on firefox, but works on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836433/model-fetch-success-callback-does-not-fire-on-firefox-but-works-on-chrome) but there is no javascript code in that.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the ajax call return?

Answer (score 2):

Try also passing dataType: 'json' to the fetch.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with fetch only ever returning my error callback.

In the end, it was because I had not specified an id in the object on the server like this:

```
{"title":"The Green Mile ","author":"Stephen King","img":"green_mile.jpg","id":2}
```

I think Backbone expects certain properties to be present in the JSON, though I was unable to find any documentation about this. The way I solved it was to do model.save() and to look at the object that was being saved.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I had the same issue because of an unsafe method incorrectly injecting NaN into the json response
    {"progress":NaN}
which failed to be correctly parsed and forced the error callback

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and it was due to using single quotes instead of double quotes to surround attributes and values in the API's JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the url outside of defaults

```
= Backbone.Model.extend({
url : "/displayPostVariables.php",
defaults:{

},
validation: {

      }
```

});