# Backbone.js fetch not working

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm having trouble getting Backbone.js fetch to work. The following code actually pulls the json from my server code, but it still ends up in the error function rather than the success one.

The server code is PHP sets the header application/json and returns valid json.

When the Javascript runs, I get the following in the console log.

```
{"id":"1011"} client.js:22
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{id: 1011,address: \"123 Main St.\"}","status":200,"statusText":"OK"} client.js:23
{"parse":true,"emulateHTTP":false,"emulateJSON":false,"xhr":{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{id: 1011,address: \"123 Main St.\"}","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}} client.js:24

$(function() {
    var Property = Backbone.Model.extend({

urlRoot: 'property'
});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('#content'),
error: function(m, xhr, opts) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(opts));
},
render: function() {
    alert("Success");
},
initialize: function() {
    var options = {};
    options.success = this.render;
    options.error = this.error;
    var property = new Property({id: "1011"});
    property.fetch(options);
}
    });
    var appview = new AppView;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it appears that Backbone.js is expecting certain data to come back in the JSON response in a particular format.

Rather than including `id: 1011` in my json response, it works if I return `"id": "1011"`

Is there documentation on this somewhere? It really tripped me up for a long time. I kept going back to my server response thinking it was something in there that's not quite right, but I was unable to figure it out.

This StackOverflow question and answer helped me though: [model.fetch always going to error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040039/model-fetch-always-going-to-error-callback)

Hopefully this question and answer will help someone else out in the future.

Comment: `id: 1011` **is not** JSON, that's just JavaScript; `"id": "1011"` or `"id": 1001` OTOH **is** JSON. See http://www.json.org/ for details on the JSON format.

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured out how silly I was being on the server side code. I was handcoding JSON rather than just building a PHP object and calling json_encode and letting that function handle it.

And even if I don't include the id for the object, Backbone.js figures it out.

Comment: Hand-coding JSON is false laziness :)

Comment: Totally. I looked at the code and I was like, "That's stupid. There's a function for that."

Comment: Please mark this as answer so it's not sitting waiting to be answered :).